# WCF Custom Binding - The Scheme cannot be computed because this CustomBinding lacks a TransportBindingElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I am using custom binding and getting following error :

**The Scheme cannot be computed for this binding because this CustomBinding lacks a TransportBindingElement.  Every binding must have at least one binding element that derives from TransportBindingElement.**

My Custom Binding Code as follows

```
public class MyCustomBinding : Binding
    {
        private HttpTransportBindingElement transport;
        private BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding;

        public MyCustomBinding()
            : base()
        {
            this.InitializeValue();
        }
        public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
        {
            BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();
            elements.Add(this.encoding);
            elements.Add(this.transport);
            return elements;
        }
        public override string Scheme
        {
            get { return this.transport.Scheme; }
        }
        private void InitializeValue()
        {
            this.transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            this.encoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomBindingCollectionElement : BindingCollectionElement
    {
        // type of custom binding class
        public override Type BindingType
        {
            get { return typeof(MyCustomBinding); }
        }

       //  override ConfiguredBindings
        public override ReadOnlyCollection<IBindingConfigurationElement> ConfiguredBindings
        {
            get
            {
                return new ReadOnlyCollection<IBindingConfigurationElement>(
                new List<IBindingConfigurationElement>());
            }
        }

        // return Binding class object
        protected override Binding GetDefault()
        {
            return new MyCustomBinding();
        }

        public override bool ContainsKey(string name) {

            return true;
        }

        protected override bool TryAdd(string name, Binding binding, Configuration config)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Web.config code is as follows:

```
<extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <!--<add name="ProxyElement" type="ADHA.Model.HttpTransportBindingElementProxy, ADHA"/>-->
      <add name="MyCustomBinding" type="ADHA.Model.MyCustomBindingCollectionElement,ADHA,
               Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>

<service>      
    <services>
 <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyCustomBinding" contract="ADHA.IADHAService">
            </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="customBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>      
    </services>

<bindings>
   <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyCustomBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                                 maxSessionSize="2048">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                     maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          </binaryMessageEncoding>        
          <textMessageEncoding
            messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004"/>
         <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
        </binding>

      </customBinding>

    </bindings>
```

Someone please tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: I guess you have taken that (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/243357/WCF-Custom-Binding) as an example. Did you try to run your service first without binding customization in config? Try to delete ``<binding name="MyCustomBinding">`` and run with default transport and message settings. If it is ok, the problem with binding customization  in xml. I guess you binding ``<binding name="MyCustomBinding">`` is not match automatically the binding of type ``MyCustomBinding `` in custom type. There should be the ways to say that the binding with configuration name A is the instance of the .NET type B

Comment: @Mimas Service is working fine with wsHTTP binding but not working with custom binding actually I have to do this https://www.develop.com/building-scalable-and-secure-wcf-services that is why I am using Custom Binding

Comment: No questions to your custom binding. As I see the problem is with how you  try to apply it to your service (application cannot recognize you new binding in the config file). If you want to do that **via config file**, you must implement all the stuff needed to make it working: **custom BindingElement, custom BindingCollectionElement** etc and make proper configuration (I gave you an example). From my point of view the easiest way to do that, is to take a sample project and change it for your needs. The links to the projects see in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

See an example here (http://webservices20.blogspot.de/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html). There is also a [project on github](https://github.com/yaronn/ClearUsernameBinding) with good working sample.
You should refer your new type with the new name, defined in extension description. Like that:

```
<extensions>
  <bindingExtensions>
   <add name="myCustomBinding" type="ADHA.Model.MyCustomBindingCollectionElement, ADHA,
           Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>

<bindings>
  <myCustomBinding>
   <binding name="myCustomBindingConfig"> 
     <binaryMessageEncoding />
     <httpsTransport />
   </binding>
  </myCustomBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service>
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="myCustomBindingConfig"
       contract="ADHA.IADHAService">
        </endpoint>
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="customBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>      
</services>
```

For that you will have to create a Custom BindingElement with the Configuration.StandardBindingElement and a custom BindingCollectionElement with the Configuration.StandardBindingCollectionElement.

One more [step by step example is here.](http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/01/wcf-custom-binding-by-configuration-and-by-binding-standardbindingelement-and-standardbindingcollectionelement/)